# New Relic iOS app doesn't notify of downtime anymore

Tags: newrelic

Not sure when this started happening, but I used to get alerts on my iPhone from the New Relic app when our site went non-responsive. I don't think we changed anything. How can I re-enable these alerts?

Comment: I'm going to post some general tips as an 'answer' but you should probably open a ticket at support.newrelic.com so that Support can look at your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Account Preferences menu includes some settings for how you're receiving Apple Push Notifications (APN's), the first thing to check is that you're getting push notifications at all, by clicking 'send test notification' under 'My Preferences' to make sure you're getting them at all. The button's [right here.](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s273/sh/37416568-175c-44dd-9295-373a02491337/49183070a3daf58b14977408793c7756)

If not, the best process to get it fixed is to delete the app from your phone *and* remove the phone's listing from your Account Preferences menu, then re-add both.

If you're getting other push notifications but not the downtime alerts, then you should take a look at the new 'alert policies' menu under 'Tools' in the left-hand toolbar and make sure you've got that notification channel enabled. Here's some documentation with more detail on this process (my apologies if you've read this already):

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alert-policies/alert-policies-dashboard

Comment: Can you give me instructions as to where I can find the test notification? I don't see one for the NR iOS app.

Comment: clarified a bit in an edit, but it's under 'My Preferences', once you've got an iOS app set up on your device you should see your device listed there. Looks like this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s273/sh/37416568-175c-44dd-9295-373a02491337/49183070a3daf58b14977408793c7756

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize notifications were tied to a specific device. Removing from NR and re-adding fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Just to note: I'm going to talk to our iOS team to verify that this really is a necessary limitation. For now though I'm glad you're working!